# Object typing where value is array of keys or empty array

Tags: typescript

I am looking to type an object like this:

```
const example = {
  'meow': [],
  'woof': [],
  'quack': [],
  'all': ['meow', 'woof', 'quack'],
  'meowWoof': ['meow', 'woof'],
}
```

Above, would be valid. You see it is meta because the values, have to be arrays which values are keys in the object itself.

However this would not because `DOGS` is not a key.

```
const example = {
  'meow': [],
  'woof': [],
  'quack': [],
  'all': ['meow', 'DOGS', 'quack'],
  'meowWoof': ['meow', 'woof'],
}
```

I'd be OK with wrapping this object in a function to get the typing working.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a generic helper function like this:

```
const asExample = <T extends Record<keyof T, Array<keyof T>>>(t: T) => t;
```

It behaves how you seem to want it:

```
const example = asExample({
    'meow': [],
    'woof': [],
    'quack': [],
    'all': ['meow', 'woof', 'quack'],
    'meowWoof': ['meow', 'woof'],
}); // okay

const badExample = asExample({
    'meow': [],
    'woof': [],
    'quack': [],
    'all': ['meow', 'DOGS', 'quack'],  // error here
    'meowWoof': ['meow', 'woof'],
});
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAogDzgWwA4BsCmMC8MAPACow7JQ5gAmEMASjqAE41EDWOAniAGYwSAGhgBBFizjdOPfoIB8igBRQAXIICUBeTCgBuAFAHQkWBXTY8hBCgu4lAbwMwXMAORocIAO5v1AbQBdIWdXN28Qfj8YIJDXdwBHAFc4YA5o2NCXNzgsLAyPL18RcMi+NxLk1PTgrPdPHwB1MoKG4vcIqNqAXw09GAB6AZgQDikjE2gYACM4GltMXAJ4JFRFnEc6wp8M2vjSqIC9sKq03biw3PyA7fa3ABEAeQBxAGUKxJSz4Jch8gkQCwYAALHAsHBbNrNQ4xW4fA7lHp9IxAA)